# VMWare shared folder: hgfs missing

Tags: vmware-workstation

I am trying to share folders from my host Windows system with my VMWare Ubuntu 32 bit guest system. I have open-vmware-tools installed. VMWare Tools does not synchronize guest time with host. Sharing folders is enabled, and I have two shared folders.

ls media shows only floppy, floppy0, and a folder with my name (which contains nothing). /mnt contains nothing, so of course if I try to `mount -t vmhgfs .host:/ /myfolder`, it complains that there is no such device. ( have since done `mkdir /mnt/hgfs`, but with no effect.)

So: what do I do to get the machine to mount the shared file system? TIA.